# What if ssh does not work?

Tags: updates, appcenter, shell, ssh

Some of you use ssh in the shell, but this does not work with elementary on a Tuxedo-Laptop. I tried to find the status of ssh, but this doesn' t show either. I tried to install putty - no success.
Could it be a deeper problem?
Any ideas?

Comment: What errors you get? Did you try to install `openssh-clients`?

Comment: The error is Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: You dont have permissions to access remote server. What command do you run? What server are you trying to access?

Comment: ssh xxx@xxx.hoster.com This is how others connect to the hosting-server.

Comment: You probably don't have private key or password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you got the right connection information. This is not a system error.

More information about SSH and how to use it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Shell#Client_usage
(ArchLinux wiki. Excellent documentation)

If you need to add a PublicKey to connect (As the error message suggest) and you're unaware of it, you should try contacting your hosting provider for support.

Comment: In fact: I get a package with 8 different websites/subdomains. It is my first step using ssh. Thank you for supporting.